# Limit Points and Closures in Topology

Tags: general-topology

I am in an introductory Topology course and the text is not very helpful.

One of the example questions state the following:

Let A = [0, 1) u (1,2) be a subset of (R,U).  Then find the following:
Int(A), Bd(A), Ext(A), A', A u A', Cl(A)

I know that Int(A) = (0,1) u (1,2), Bd(A) = {0,1,2}, and Ext(A) = (-inf,0)u(2,inf).

I think A' (the set of all limit points of A) is [0,2] but I am not sure.

I know that if A is a subset of R, then Cl(A) = A u A'.  I'm not sure what either side is.

Comment: With regards to your text, I have fond memories of [this book](http://www.topologywithouttears.net/topbook.pdf) which pretty much saved my undergrad degree from disaster

Comment: Thank you very much.  That book will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derived set of $A$, $A'$, is the set of all limit points and a point $p \in A$ is a limit point of the subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ iff every open set $U$ containing $p$ also contains a point of $A$ different from $p$, i.e.

$$U \: \text{open},\: p \in U \implies (U \setminus \{p\}) \cap A \neq \emptyset$$

So you are correct in that the derived set is

$A' = [0, 2]$

Then the closure is

$\text{Cl}(A) = A \cup A' = ([0,1) \cup (1,2)) \cup [0, 2] = [0, 2]$